# Why does one of my project's GUIDs change when I build the project in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, guid, solution

For two of my VS 2005 C++ projects, VS wants to write to the .sln file when I build the projects.  I have got a number of other VS 2005 C++ projects where this is not the case.  It is a problem as due to the fact that we have ClearCase source control integrated with our VS 2005 installations and when we try and run an overnight build via batch files, the build pauses as a ClearCase check out dialog box is displayed.

Looking at what VS is changing in the .sln files, it is the second GUID on the project line.

Before building:

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "InterCommClientB", "InterCommClientB.vcproj", "{A2AF232A-7F27-4340-81D5-8ABFD10994D2}"
```

After building:

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "InterCommClientB", "InterCommClientB.vcproj", "{67BE85B7-3234-484E-88FB-4F0E42096583}"
```

Any help gratefully received.  I am new to VS 2005, as we have only recently migrated from VC++ 6.0, so apologies if I have missed something obvious.

We are running VS 2005 Professional Edition, with SP1 installed.

Regards,

Greg.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. It seems that when converting projects from old versions of VS (like 6 or 2003) VS 2010 is not adding Project GUID to the .vcxproj file. Because of that when you open solution including such project VS will recreate GUID for such project, and will change .sln file but will not change .vcxproj file. So another time you open such solution the situation will be the same and the .sln file may change again.

See this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586258/missing-projectguid-in-vcxproj-files

Comment: I've seen this effect too. It can happen if you have a project that is used in two solutions and if one of them hasn't yet been updated to the current VisualStudio version then you can get a new GUID created.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here, but it looks like some changes have been made to the InterCommClientB project(project, not the files in the project). When this happens the sln is updated, in this case only the project GUID.

My best guess to resolve this issue would be to manually build the solution and then checkin the changes. This way the sln file won't change on build.

My second best guess is that you already made this changes at your computer and it is working fine, but you did not get lattest version on the pc where you do the night build .

Answer (score 0):

This might be totally out there - but sometimes Visual Studio fails to check-in a Solution file when it's been modified and while the Solution is open in Visual Studio. Try closing Visual Studio, and only then committing the Solution file.

If it isn't that, there might be some other agency causing the Solution file to need to change the GUIDs its using. In one instance, I was using .NET tools from National Instruments, and they has a licensing scheme that would trigger that sort of action (modification of extraneous files for not good reason) whenever I went to do a rebuild.

Please take a careful look at the output from the build (in the log, or the output window) - you may find some further clues there!